# Ionic 3: executing a funtion with toggle button

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a toggle button and two functions. I want one of the functions to be called when the toggle button is on, and the other to be called when the toggle button is in off state. How can I do that?

Comment: you can have on click method and then use "if" to check checked property

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy actually if you make use of [angular forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). You just need to subscribe to the toggle **control** that we define in the **FormGroup**. You can subscribe to the value of the entire form or just the value of an individual control as I've done below. Following the angular documentation, I usually use a separate function to construct my FormGroup and then call that function, **buildForm()** inside the constructor.

```js
buildForm(): void {
  this.myCoolForm = this._fb.group({
    superCoolToggle: ['']
  })
  
  this.form.controls['superCoolToggle'].valueChanges.subscribe( value => {
    if (value === true) {
      // something here
    } else if (value === false) {
      // something different here
    }
  })

}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="myCoolForm">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label> Sam</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle formControlName="superCoolToggle"></ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```